# Changing a root password for SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, linux, windows-server-2008, snort

So i am running a linux box as well as WindowsServer2008. Right now i am trying to install barnyard to work on my linux machine, but i am stuck at a part in the process where linux asks for my SQL root password. This may be a stupid question but I am having difficulty finding where i would go to change the password for the SQL account. Both the WS2008 server and the linux are near-fresh installs with little on them but snort and MSSQL respectively. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank You!!

Comment: Are you talking about the OS account, or the DB Server account?  The DB Server account is typically 'sa' and password/account settings can be accessed from SSMS under the Security Folder.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the work on Linux:

```
#Stop mysql service
service mysql stop (RHEL based OS)
service mysqld stop (Debian based OS)

#Start mysql in safe mode:
mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables &

#Log into mysql as root (No password is required)
mysql -uroot

#Select "mysql" database (where we need to make changes)
use mysql;

#Reset Password mynewpassword should be changed with password you wish to have
update user set password=PASSWORD("mynewpassword") where User='root';

#Flush privileges
flush privileges;

#Quit from mysql
quit

#Restart mysql service as normal mode
service mysql restart (RHEL based OS)
service mysqld restart (Debian based OS)
```